# Weird win sock bug on non blocking recv()

Tags: c, windows, winsock

This is my receive file function for a non overlapped socket.

```c
            HANDLE recvfile = CreateFile(fileinfo[0], FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            if (recvfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                sockprintf(sockfd, "[Error Creating File] : %ld", GetLastError());
            }
            else {
                memset(recvbuf, '\0', BUFFER); // Clear main buffer
                int total = 0; // Total bytes received
                // set_blocking_mode(sockfd, FALSE);
                do{ // IF Total is equal to expected bytes. Break the loop, And stop receiving.
                    fsize = recv(sockfd, recvbuf, BUFFER, 0); // Receive file
                    if (fsize == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAECONNRESET)
                    {
                        connected = FALSE;
                        printf("[X] Connection interrupted while receiving file %s for %s size.", fileinfo[0], fileinfo[1]);
                    }
                    write = WriteFile(recvfile, recvbuf, fsize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL); // Write file data to file
                    total += fsize; // Add number of bytes received to total.
                } while(total != expected);
                // set_blocking_mode(sockfd, TRUE);
                if (write == FALSE)
                {
                    sockprintf(sockfd, "[Error Writing file %s of %s size] Error : %ld.", fileinfo[0], fileinfo[1], GetLastError());
                }
                else {
                    sockprintf(sockfd, "\n[ Received File : %s ]\n[ File Size : %s bytes ]\n[ Bytes written : %ld ]\n", fileinfo[0], fileinfo[1], dwBytesWritten);
                }
                CloseHandle(recvfile);
            }
```

This is working excellent! File Transfer is almost instant and with no errors or corrupted buffers.
I'm on Visual studio 2019. The Problem is, When I compile and move the Executable to a test Virtual machine. The program crashes. Tested on Windows 10 and also Windows 7.

Crash occurs on the do while loop. The program does not break out of it. I have tried compiling with msvc (the latest) and also mingw-w64 and also tdm gcc. The bug is same.
The code only works on my own machine, It's not working on any other.

Comment: Err... why set non-blocking?  What happens if a WSAEWOULDBLOCK error is returned?

Comment: `} while(total != expected);` seems ambitious, but then it is not shown where they are updated.

Comment: @MartinJames Correction, I forgot to add, non-blocking was set to only test. I should update the question.

Comment: Why does the program not break out of it? You should be able to find out.

Comment: @ryyker Hey, I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: @user253751 The code is working, But only on the same machine as it was compiled. If I test it on any other Machine, For tests, A VM, The do while loop never breaks. Can't figure out why.

Comment: This statement needs clarification:  _When I compile and move the Executable to a test Virtual machine_.  So, you are compiling on one machine, but then moving to another machine and attempting to run, and it fails.  Is the machine the `exe` is copied to compatible with the one it was compiled on, i.e. same OS?  Has the same libraries (and other support resources) available as the build machine?

Comment: Where does 'expected' get loaded?

Comment: _"Crash occurs on the do while loop. The program does not break out of it."_ leads me to look at the exit criteria of the loop, and naturally the evaluation of `total != expected` is key here, but I cannot see where those values are updated in the code.  Where are they changed.  Am I missing something?  (I do see `total += fsize;`, but where is `expected`?)

Comment: @coderman Well then find out why. That's kinda your job as a programmer.

Comment: @ryyker I compile static, The code is working, Yes it is compatible because the code runs. The bug is that, Whenever the code reaches the do while loop part, It just never breaks the loop. Let me update the question and add a example gif.

Comment: @MartinJames memset(recvbuf, '\0', BUFFER);
            int return_code = recv(sockfd, recvbuf, BUFFER, 0);
            if (return_code == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAECONNRESET)
            {
                break;
            }
            split(recvbuf, fileinfo, ":");
            int expected = atoi(fileinfo[1]);

Comment: It will not exit the loop if 'expected' is bad.  Where does that file size come from?

Comment: @coderman Maybe you should print out fsize and total and expected each time the loop runs, and then you can see why the loop is still running?

Comment: The file information file name and size is received first, And split. ``expected`` is the expected file size that the server side sends. So we only receive ``expected`` amount of bytes. That code works but doesn't work if I compile it (static) and move it on a test machine. Then it never breaks the do while loop and keeps receiving.

Comment: Are you 100% that the problem is here, and not in the peer sending the data?

Comment: @MartinJames I did exactly this! And yes, It's working on another project. I think the issue is the way I'm compiling or some preprocessor triggering the bug.

Comment: The problem is here and not in server side, Because I Tested the same function in another project, And that seems to be working.

Comment: 'The file information file name and size is received first' hmm.. do you print out the expected size?

Comment: @MartinJames I did print out expected sizes when I was testing, Once I had confidence that this is working, I moved on to further tests. As I Said, The code works, Just not if I move the exe to another machine.

Comment: ' I did print out expected sizes when I was testing' - print it out every time.

Comment: TBH, the record of SO posters, when it comes to transferring structured data like file data, is umm... 'less than optimal':)  They misuse the byte streaming of TCP and/or library calls that MUST be supplied with NUL-terminated char arrays...

Comment: @MartinJames I just tested, The file is being received on other test machines, But the loop isn't breaking. I can confirm this as any data I'm sending after sending the file is also being written to the file. Means that it's receiving more than ``expected`` in the loop.

Comment: @coderman SO FIND OUT WHY IT'S RECEIVING MORE. Are there extra bytes in the file? If so, are they always in the same place? Or is the file the correct size? Maybe fsize is counted incorrectly? (hint hint)

Comment: I do not trust your conclusions.  Use wireshark to be absolutely certain that you are debugging the correct peer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for more than just WSAECONNRESET.  Pretty much every error (save for "would block" in non-blocking) is fatal and indicates the socket should be aborted. Don't forget that `recv` can and will return `0` if the remote side closes its end gracefully.

This whole loop:

```
            do{ // IF Total is equal to expected bytes. Break the loop, And stop receiving.
                fsize = recv(sockfd, recvbuf, BUFFER, 0); // Receive file
                if (fsize == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAECONNRESET)
                {
                    connected = FALSE;
                    printf("[X] Connection interrupted while receiving file %s for %s size.", fileinfo[0], fileinfo[1]);
                }
                write = WriteFile(recvfile, recvbuf, fsize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL); // Write file data to file
                total += fsize; // Add number of bytes received to total.
            } while(total != expected);
```

Should be:

```
            do{ 
                fsize = recv(sockfd, recvbuf, BUFFER, 0); // Receive file
                if (fsize == SOCKET_ERROR) {

                    int err = WSAGetLastError();
                    if (err == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {

                        // ISSUE SELECT CALL HERE TO WAIT FOR MORE DATA

                    }
                    else {
                        // FATAL ERROR - abort
                        break;
                    }

                }
                else if (fsize == 0) {
                    break;  // remote connection terminated cleanly.
                }
                else {
                    write = WriteFile(recvfile, recvbuf, fsize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
                    total += fsize;
                }
            } while(total != expected);
```

Comment: Is there really a reasonable expectation here, or in OP code that given `expected` is input using `int expected = atoi(fileinfo[1]);` that `total` and `expected` are likely to be perfectly aligned?  i.e.  be `==`?

Comment: @ryyker I would expect an exact match, assuming that the fileinfo has been transferred completely and correctly.....

Comment: @MartinJames - okay, I will read up on that topic little more.  It always appears to be risky when setting anything `==` when it comes to anything resembling `tcp/ip` sockets based data transfer.  As it turns out the problem here was indeed that `fileinfo[]` was not being initialized properly before being evaluated on OP's _new machine_.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, IT seems the problem was my own ignorance, The server side was supplying the file information too quickly, And due to that, `fileinfo[]` was mixed up. And thus the loop not breaking. Still don't understand why it worked on the development machine tho. Anyway, As expected the problem was not in the Code that I have posted in this Question. Thanks ya'll!
The solution was to send the data with a small time sleep. :)

Comment: I'll still stand by my answer. You need to be more diligent checking for errors.  Otherwise, your `fsize` of `-1` will get cast to unsigned when you invoke WriteFile and weird things will happen.

Comment: That is not the answer.  You need a real protocol that will work even if one byte is read per recv call.